# How To: Align Button Text, and Icon

Tags: button, xamarin.forms

I want to left justify the Button Text and Icon.  How can this be done?  Preferable without creating a custom control renderer for each target platform.

I've used the Button's ContentLayout property to position the Icon to the Left of the Text, but the Button does not have a HorizontalTextAlignment property.

XAML - Snippet

```
<StackLayout.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />                        
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />                        
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />                        
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="LawnGreen"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentLayout" Value="Left,5" />
    </Style>
</StackLayout.Resources>

<Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" Style="{DynamicResource buttonStyle}"
    CommandParameter="MainPage"                         
    Text="Lock"                        
    Image="locked.png"/>
```

I would expect the Icon, and Text to be left justified, but the default behavior his Center justification.

Comment: could you show the effect ?

Comment: I’m not in front of my computer but have you tried the Margin property?

Comment: You will have to write custom renderer's for this my friend